# MDC-like (Mozilla Documentation Center) resource for WebKit?

Tags: html, documentation, webkit

Playing around with latest HTML5 features feels nice, but it tends to be quite troublesome in the end, as standards and their browser specific implementations continue to evolve. Mozilla has a great resource - [MDN Doc Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs), where they continuously document all the changes that Gecko undergoes. I wonder if there is anything similar for WebKit, for both Safari and Chrome?

Comment: @Yi Jiang why have you changed mutate to involve? :D In fact I think mutate is much better term for what they do, especially Mozilla.

Comment: @Yi Jiang I think you meant evolve, not involve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the doc centres for all major browsers:

References - Basically exactly the same as safari link for IE/FF + Opera

**Chrome:** (thanks to @TomTu)

https://www.chromium.org/developers

**Firefox:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/

**Opera:**

https://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto23/#html (very very good)

**Safari:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001267-SW1

**IE:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902517.aspx

Comment: Thanks for collecting all of these in one place. Although I'm pretty sure now that there is no MDC-like resource for other browsers. http://www.chromium.org/developers looks like useful resource for developers of the Chrome itself rather then - web-developers, but it has some useful external links (not Chrome or WebKit specific though) too. I doubt there will be any better answer, so...

Answer (score 2):

To complement Myles' list I'll add the google's chromium for develoeprs page.

**Chrome/Chromium**

http://www.chromium.org/developers

Comment: Cheers man I'll add it to my answer, completely forgot about chrome!

Comment: @Myles Gray: Cheers, they aren't really up-front with their dev website so it's easy to be missed :)

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [Safari CSS Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Introduction.html) should qualify for this. There's also the [Safari Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action) for broader topics like developing extensions and websites for (Mobile) Safari.

Comment: Can this qualify as a resource for Chromium as well? I know they are meant to be the same thing, but quite often they are not.

Comment: Actually I can't find a description for FileReader object on there, can you?

Comment: @jayarjo Hmm, apparently not. To be fair, I only use MDC on a daily basis, but I have seen this reference used for WebKit CSS extensions. The [Surfin' Safari blog](http://webkit.org/blog/) is where the WebKit team announces new features, maybe you'll have better luck there?

Comment: Doesn't look like an informative place :(

Answer (score 1):

[QuirksMode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) has a wide range of [compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) for various browser features. They also have [HTML5 compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html) that indicate browser support for HTML5 features for multiple versions of IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, and Konqueror. Additionally, there are some good [tidbits](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) of information about browser-specific issues and implementations.

Answer (score -1):

MDC is a wiki which means you can edit and add documentation for other browsers too :)

Comment: ... and how does that fact actually help the OP here?