# Does Google Chrome follow Firefox specifications

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

I use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) as my Javascript and CSS reference. Considering that the creator of the Javascript language works at Mozilla, I assume this is the best reference. However, every now and then I hear about new features that are available in Google Chrome but Firefox doesn't have them yet. It makes me wonder:

1. Where and how these new specs are announced?
2. For the things that are similar between Chrome and Firefox, is it safe to assume that Chrome follows Firefox standards? I get the impression that Chrome's main aim is to be a faster Firefox (?) and that's why it doesn't have a vast wiki like Firefox.
3. If I'm developing for Chrome (let's say making Chrome apps for example), can I rely on Firefox's MDN as a reference? I couldn't find something equivalent to MDN for Chrome.

I'll mark the best reply as answer. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919617/mdc-like-mozilla-documentation-center-resource-for-webkit

Comment: Google and Mozilla works to their own projects, period. What they do is to implement the specs from the W3C and WHATWG, and they can do it in slightly different ways until the specs reach a fairly stable state. Anyway, they surely talk a lot to avoid absurd inconsistencies like there when the IE-Netscape war was raging. Take for example the WebRTC thing, that was once incompatible between Firefox and Chrome, but they fixed it recently. Anyway, it's Chrome that usually implements new things and paves the way for the other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All modifications are announced in the [google chrome release blog](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com.au/).
2. As far as I see it, chrome isn't just a faster Firefox. It's a different browser altogether, that provides, in my view, much better user customization (as seen in things like themes) as well as having a developer base which provides some really good [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=en). As to the wiki, chrome is considerably newer, however, it provides some really good user support via chrome support.
3. AFAIK, spidermonkey (Firefox) and v8 (chrome) engines are reasonably similar in terms of javascript, so you should be alright just using MDN. There's a webmaster.SE thread about the issue [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-are-the-differences-between-firefoxs-javascript-engine-and-chromes-v8).